# Can not convert from Class<PowerMockRunner> to Class<? extends Runner>

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit4, powermock

I am trying to write Unit test cases using power mockito.

When using annotations `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` I am getting the following compilation error:-

```
TypeMismatch: cannot convert from Class<PowerMockRunner> to Class<? extends Runner>
```

Here is the code snippet. Using junit 4.8.1 and power mock 1.6.2.

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class XXXTest {
    @Test
    public void testOne() {
        if (true)
            System.out.println("Success");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try junit 4.11 and powermock-module-junit4 1.6.0, it works for me!

Comment: Harry thanks for ur time. Finally I figured out my error. I downloaded and added Powermock-Module-Junit4 jar and did not add the dependent jar Powermock-Module-Junit4-Common.jar. When added common jar Powermock-Module-Junit4-Common resolved the error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I downloaded and added Powermock-Module-Junit4 jar and did not add the dependent jar Powermock-Module-Junit4-Common.jar. When added common jar Powermock-Module-Junit4-Common resolved the error.

Thanks,
Vasu.